# Large blank space below banner but only on IE6

Tags: web, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to fix this issue for three days, but still no success. Site displays correctly on all browsers except IE6. There is large whitespace only on IE6.

What could be problem? Is that some known bug with IE6?

Here is a screenshot:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/W/jG/3fe30PkP/issue.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code the specific reason for the problem is hard to say. But general guideline is that you need ie specific stylesheets. You need ie6 specific stylesheets more. You may need to create a number of stylesheets for each version and add something like this to your site.

```
  <!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">@import url(/styles/ie_fixes.css');</style><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">@import url(/styles/ie_fixes_6.css');</style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">@import url(/styles/ie_fixes_7.css');</style>
    <![endif]-->
```

And in each of the included stylesheets you write css to fix the various problems you identify in the various browsers.

Comment: It seems like IE doesnt load conditional CSS

Comment: Now it works, it was server issue. Thanks for answer. 
I created file directly on server and now it works.
It didnt work when I uploaded file via ftp. Dont know why.

Comment: great. I was going to suggest that maybe the browser cache was causing problems...

Answer (score 0):

You should post a screenshot of your problem, since not a lot of people here has IE6 installed to reproduce the bug.
I would suggest you to have a look to the border bug of IE6, though:

http://www.simple-site.eu/test-lab/ie-bugs/ie6-border-bug.html

Comment: Here you can see screenshot under IE6
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/W/jG/3fe30PkP/issue.jpg

Comment: My guess is that because of the IE6 border bug, the div containing the road image splits in two lines, creating that gap.

Comment: When I remove margin-top it shows correctly in IE6, but it gets corrupted in FF.
<br/>
#content {<br/>
 margin-top:280px;<br/>
 padding : 5px;<br/>
} <br/>